# In python: How to perform regular expression search on "circular" string

Tags: python, regex

Assume:

```
string="aacctcaaaca"
find="aaa"
```

and I want to find all occurrences of find.

Usually, I would do

```
re.findall(find, string)
```

The catch is that the string is circular, i.e. the start/end of the string is irrelevant. So the "aaa" made up of the first two + last a's should also be counted.

In addition, I would like to find the start position of the match (6 and 10 in the above example)

I was thinking about adding string[0:len(find)-1] to string and performing the re on that new string
i.e.

```
re.findall(find, string+string[0:len(find)-1])
```

Does that sound right? Any other ideas/suggestions?

Comment: But if the string is truly circular, you would get an infinite number of results...

Comment: true, i guess I need to break the re after it has gone around the circle once...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current approach seems perfectly reasonable.  Another option is to just concatenate the entire string and ignore any matches that start after the wrapping.

For example:

```
string="aacctcaaaca"
find="aaa"
[m.group(0) for m in re.finditer(find, string+string) if m.start() < len(string)]
```

This is a bit more extensible because you can use an arbitrary regex such as `a{3,}` where you might not be able to rely on `len(find)`.

As suggested by mgilson in comments you can make this more efficient by using itertools so that you aren't finding repeat matches unnecessarily.

It would look something like this:

```
from itertools import takewhile
takewhile(lambda m: m.start() < len(string), re.finditer(find, string+string))
```

Note that this will return an iterable of match objects instead of a list of the matched substrings.

Comment: Might be a use-case for `itertools.takewhile` (or a generator function) as then you would short-circuit the `finditer`

Answer (score 0):

```
def cyclic_substring(string,substring):
  new_string=2*string
  m=len(substring)
  n=len(string)
  if m<n:
    if substring in new_string :
      return True
  else : 
      return False
#lets take a example of principal
cyclic_substring("principal","ipalp")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: There is no use of Regular Expressions here.

Comment: In addition, I would like to find the start position of the match (6 and 10 in the above example)